# Poner dos carruseles en una misma página

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap, carrusel

Estaba viendo como paginar una página con varios carruseles en los que se contenga una cantidad especifica de imágenes.

En el ejemplo que tengo aparece en la página pero lo estoy manejando con un modal.

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo podría paginar los carruseles para que uno se vea en una página y otro al darle clic se vea en otra y no se vean en la misma página?

Espero me puedan orientar de antemano gracias.

Yo ocupo Bootstrap 3.3.7 y el ejemplo que encontré utiliza éste. Solo que no sé como poder paginarlo. Espero me puedan dar ideas de como podría modificarlo o si es posible hacer esto anterior.

La página es la siguiente https://codepen.io/Baldan/pen/YvEoBm/

Y mi ejemplo es algo así. Viene dentro de un modal pero se desacomodan los  botones de *next* y me aparecen los dos carruseles juntos y no se paginan. No sé si sería mejor con un `<nav>` o algo parecido para que se separen y se vean según el botón que pique, aunque solo al apretar el botón como que me mueve al carrusel como en su posición pero es todo lo que hace.

Actualización ya tengo la parte de los dos carruseles juntos pero no se si habrá alguna forma de paginarlos e intente meterlo con un nav pero me aparece en la misma pagina

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
  <title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Button Methods</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.21.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
     <script src=" https://pagination.js.org/dist/2.1.5/pagination.js"></script>
    
<script src="js/bootstrap-table-pagination.js"></script>
<script src="js/pagination.js"></script>

  <style>
       #myCarousel {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
            
           position: center;
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column-reverse nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
           height: 40%;
           width: 40%;
        }

        #myCarousel2 {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
            
           position: center;
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column-reverse nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
           height: 40%;
           width: 40%;
        }

        .item img {
            max-width: 50%;
             height: 40%;
           width: 40%;
        }

        .item active {
            max-width: 50%;
             height: 40%;
           width: 40%;
        }
     </style>
 </head> 
    
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-mdb-target="#myModal" data-mdb-toggle="modal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal top fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true" data-mdb-backdrop="true" data-mdb-keyboard="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>


        <div class="modal-body">


          <div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">2</a></li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="tab-content">

    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <!-- uno -->
      <h2>Carousel Example 1</h2>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533450718592-29d45635f0a9?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8anBnfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
          <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://demos.maugelves.com/jpg-formats/kitty-progresivo.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chicago</h3>
          <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://kinsta.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/tiger-jpg.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>New York</h3>
          <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <!--dos-->
      
  <h2>Carousel Example 2</h2>
  <div id="myCarousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://cdn.computerhoy.com/sites/navi.axelspringer.es/public/styles/1200/public/media/image/2017/07/246288-cuando-usar-jpg-gif-png-raw-otros-formatos-imagen.png?itok=Nj8Uh-W0" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
          <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://idegrafico.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Las-imagenes-raw-son-los-negativos-digitales.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Chicago</h3>
          <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://ntsi1415juannavarro.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/ntsi.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>New York</h3>
          <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>
    </div>


    </div>

   
  </div>
</div>


      </div>


       </div>
     </div>

   </div>
 </div>   

</body>
    
</html>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Antes de nada, tienes dos elementos en el DOM con el mismo `id`. Deberías cambiarles el identificador a ambos carruseles para que ambos funcionen correctamente sin interferencias entre ellos.

Comment: ya modifique esa parte, estoy intentando con un nav pero no me  funciona del todo bien

Comment: Cómo así que se vea en otra página? Al hacer click el botón, que se abra el modal con el carousel en otra página???